# Invalid WatchKit Support mail from apple after successful submission to iTunes using xcode6.2

Tags: watchkit, xcode-6.2

I have created an iPhone app using xCode 6.1 and then for iWatch and submitted it using xCode 6.2, but after successful submission when I check on iTunes Connect, it shows `Status: Invalid binary` and I am getting the following email from Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "##". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid WatchKit Support - The bundle contains an invalid
>   implementation of WatchKit. The app may have been built or signed with
>   non-compliant or pre-release tools. Visit developer.apple.com for more
>   information.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

How can I fix this?